# Two view models ,one for the whole page & the other for a small area

Tags: knockout.js

I am aware that  `ko.applyBindings` can take a second parameter which is the DOM element that it will bind to

but my case is different i have a big page i want to specify a viewmodel for it by using 
 `ko.applyBindings(bigModel)`

and then there is a small sidebar section which is in the middle of the page i want to specify another view model for it by using  `ko.applyBindings(smallModel, $("#sidebar")[0])`

when i use bounded attributes using knockout in the small `#sidebar` section it throws an error `Unable to parse bindings` yet it still bind the values (Ex. `<span 'text:propertyOnSmallModel' />`) i after that tried to add these attributes as empty attributes on the `bigModel` , it didnt throw.

How can i apply this , use two view models one for the whole page and the other for a specific section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell Knockout.js to [stop binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) using this handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function ()
    {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;
```

Then using:

```
        <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
        <!-- /ko -->
```

html comments in your web page to stop binding.

So, you bind the bigger model to the whole page, use the above html comments to stop that model being bound on your specific section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with having child viewmodels. Add your sidebar viewmodel as a property of the parent viewmodel. Use the 'with' binding to bind the child viewmodel to your sidebar element.

Comment: the problem is i have this child viewmodel in multiple pages with different parent view model, and don't want to re assign that model as a property for its parent in every page

Comment: In that case, Paul Manzotti has given you the answer you're looking for!