# Knockout "controlsDescendantBindings" usage

Tags: knockout.js

can someone please explain to me what's the exact usage of `controlsDescendantBindings` in [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

what i got until now it's saying `Hey KO stop your binding on the descendants of the current element(the element i'm bind my custom binding to), i'll take care of binding to these descendants` am i right ?

i made simple **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/57K5J/1/)** but i don't get why only the first `span` is only updated when i comment this `return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };`

Comment: if controlsDescendantBindingsset to false, an error is thrown

Comment: @adt you right but if it cause error how can the first span get it's value correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually if you check first example of this [page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) it clearly states

> "If the value is false, then allowBindings tells Knockout that it is
>   responsible for descendant bindings so they won’t be bound as usual."

```
<div data-bind="withProperties: { emotion: 'happy' }">
    Today I feel <span data-bind="text: emotion"></span>. <!-- Displays: happy -->
</div>
```

In your fiddle div with "data-bind=withProperities" has a child element span. if **controlsDescendantBindings** were false it won't pass child span to knockout for processing. What I understand is you can control if KO should process sub elements of your custom binding.

Answer (score 0):

I use it when I want to bind one view model to the whole page (such as a navigation viewmodel), and then have specific views in a page bound to other view models. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383358/two-view-models-one-for-the-whole-page-the-other-for-a-small-area/14383433#14383433) for a small example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

When you have chain of elements and in the middle you have a custom binding for an element, if you specify

```
return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
```

inside the custom binding definition then the rest of the bindings will behave as it is defined, otherwise it will ask you to give a behavior to the rest of the elements.